# Error when compiling from Notepad++, but not PowerShell

Tags: errors, compiling, editors

I am currently writing my thesis using an existing template. I am using Notepad++ with `NppExec` to quickly save and compile everything. This had been working properly for a while, but recently I started getting an error sometimes (but not every time). In this template, a counter called `\thechapter` is used to keep track of the current chapter. The error I am getting is that `\thechapter` is undefined when I try to use the `\renewcommand{\thechapter}{6}` command. I do not get this error if I compile from Windows PowerShell.

If the information is necessary, I have added [`pstool`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/pstool) to the set of packages used, and am compiling with `pdflatex filename --shell-escape` to replace fonts in the figures with the same used in text. The same command is used in NppExec and PowerShell. One works and one sometimes doesn't. Is there a reason for this?

Comment: `\thechapter` is the visual appearance of the chapter counter and should not contain a fixed value. Without the template it is hard to suggest anything, but one thing is for sure: It cannot sometimes work and sometimes not. Also, unless you have different TeX distributions installed, you should get the same results with NP++ and PowerShell. Hence, this question, also due to its date is unclear. I VtC.